# c# use Ping.send or sendAsync always successful even without network

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I was struggling with a problem for a long time. I was using unity and I want to ping my server and router. I was using UnityPing class at the beginning and it works fine for the most of devices, but when I testing on Google Pixel(Android 7.1) it always return -1. So I tried to use System.Net.NetworkInformation to ping my server. here is my code:

```
private void PingToServer()
{
    AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping pingSender = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
    pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);
    string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    int timeout = 10000;
    PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);
    IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("119.81.194.57");
    pingSender.SendAsync(address, timeout, buffer, options, waiter);
}
private void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ping canceled.");
        ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
    }
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ping failed:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Error.ToString());
        ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
    }
    PingReply reply = e.Reply;
    int pingTime = (int)reply.RoundtripTime;
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(reply.RoundtripTime);
    ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
}
```

And It always return a RoundripTime which seems like a number make sense, but when I try to ping another ip address which is not available to reach or even turn off the internet it always return a RoundripTime with reply.status equals to IPStatus.Success. Now I'm confused, did I really ping to my remote server or not?

I did chekced some other similar questions, and it doesn't solved the problem. Some answers suggest to use SendPingAsync instead of SendAsync, but that is not possible for unity.

Comment: try use instead of `SendAsync` this : 
`PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(address, timeout, buffer, options);` and check `if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)` hope it helps.

Comment: yes I tried both SendAsync() and Send() and as I mentioned before the result is always equals to IPStatus.Success, even without internet connection.

Comment: when i use ping.send() it doesnt end with success  when i didnt have internet connection or bad IP .. but it isnt handled in event i think. Give me a sec and i post my code :)

Answer (score 0):

I have button.click event where i have this code ... and it works fine

```
    AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();
    string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    int timeout = 100;
    PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);
    IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("YourTestIP");
    PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(address, timeout, buffer, options);
    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(reply.Address.ToString());
    }
```